# Angular.js Form Invalid- Don't know why

Tags: angularjs

I don't know why, but by default in Angular.js this for is invalid by dafault(no interaction on the form):

```
  <!-- Persistence -->
  <div class="col-sm-6" ng-class="{'has-error': form.persistence.$dirty && form.persistence.$invalid}">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input for="persistence" type="checkbox"  ng-change="resetPersistenceInputBox(form, vip)" ng-model="persistanceCheckbox" ng-init="persistanceCheckbox=false">Client IP Based Persistence
      <div>
        <label class="control-label" style="font-weight: bold">Enter CIDR Netmask</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              x.x.x.x/
          </span>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-6 form-control" id="persistence" ng-init="persistanceCheckbox=false" name="persistence"
           ng-disabled="!persistanceCheckbox"
           ng-required="persistanceCheckbox"
           ng-model="vip.algorithm.persistence"
           ng-pattern='/^([0-9]|[12]\d|3[0-2])$/'
           ng-trim="true"
           placeholder="Enter a netmask between 0-32">
      </div>
      <div class="help-block" ng-show="form.persistence.$dirty && form.persistence.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="form.persistence.$error.pattern && form.persistence.$dirty">Netmask must be a number between 0-32.</span>
        <span ng-show="form.persistence.$error.required">CIDR Netmask is required while "Client IP Based Persistence" is checked.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As persistanceCheckbox is false, input#persistence is disabled.

Comment: Why would this cause the form to invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Your form is not valid until you type the input

```
 <input type="text" class="col-sm-6 form-control" id="persistence" ng-init="persistanceCheckbox=false" name="persistence"
           ng-disabled="!persistanceCheckbox"
           ng-required="persistanceCheckbox"
           ng-model="vip.algorithm.persistence"
           ng-pattern='/^([0-9]|[12]\d|3[0-2])$/'
           ng-trim="true"
           placeholder="Enter a netmask between 0-32">
```

The input is required with `ng-required="persistanceCheckbox"`
and must meet the ng-pattern : `ng-pattern='/^([0-9]|[12]\d|3[0-2])$/'`

Comment: Even if the form is disabled by default?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when the form is disable. As the input is visible and must meet requirements : required & pattern, when this input is not filled or does not match the pattern, the input will be invalid. A form is valid if all inner components are valid and invalid if one of them is invalid